# What is the "Hilbert-Bernays-Gödel axiomatic system"?

Tags: set-theory, foundations

In the preface of *Fundamentals of Abstract Analysis* by Andrew M. Gleason, he writes,

> The whole book is based on naive set theory... On the other hand, I believe that every theorem and proof will withstand a translation into the Hilbert-Bernays-Gödel axiomatic system.

I can't find anything in Google for Hilbert-Bernays-Gödel, so I imagine it might be an alternative name for something (the preface was written in 1966, so terminology may have changed). Perhaps [Von Neumann–Bernays–Gödel set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory)? Does anyone knowledgeable in foundations know what Gleason means by "the Hilbert-Bernays-Gödel axiomatic system"?

Comment: Yes; if the statement regards set theory, the axiomatization is usually called [$\mathsf {NBG}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory)

Comment: Maybe a mismatch... due to the fact that a well-known axiom system for predicate logic was due to [Hilbert & Bernays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grundlagen_der_Mathematik)